# Keep only one ID based on ifelse statement

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, duplicates

This is my df:

```
structure(list(Deelnemernr. = c("4781061T0", "4781074T0", "4781076T0", 
"4781087T0", "4781047T0", "4781027T0", "4781024T0", "4781022T0", 
"4781017T0", "4781023T0", "4781078T0", "4781079T0", "4781063T0", 
"4781008T0", "4781026T0", "4781014T0", "4781015T0", "4781072T0", 
"4781046T0", "4781032T0", "4781077T0", "4781031T0", "4781030T0", 
"4781052T0", "4781056T0", "4781004T0", "4781043T0", "4781090T0", 
"4781036T0", "4781028T0", "4781053T0", "4781068T0", "4781048T0", 
"4781041T0", "4781050T0", "4781542T0", "4781095T0", "4781020T0", 
"4781097T0", "4781182T0"), Real_sample = c("4781061T0", "4781074T0", 
"4781076T0", "4781087T0", "4781047T0", "4781027T0", "4781024T0", 
"4781022T0", "4781017T0", "4781023T0", "4781078T0", "4781079T0", 
"4781063T0", "4781008T0", "4781026T0", "4781014T0", "", "4781072T0", 
"4781061T0", "4781032T0", "4781077T0", "4781031T0", "4781030T0", 
"", "4781056T0", "4781004T0", "4781043T0", "4781090T0", "4781036T0", 
"4781028T0", "4781053T0", "4781068T0", "4781048T0", "4781041T0", 
"4781050T0", "4781542T0", "4781095T0", "4781020T0", "4781097T0", 
"4781182T0"), days = c(16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the second column 'Real_sample', rows 1 and 19 have the same ID and a value in the third column 'days'. The value in the third column is smaller in row 19 than in row 1. Based on the value in the third column, I would only like to keep the ID that has the smallest value in the third column.
This is only a subset of my dataframe so I would need a function that checks for duplicate IDs in the second column and then deletes one or more of these IDs based on the third column. It is also possible that 1 ID occurs 3 times instead of just 2. Is this possible?

So in the end, I would only be left with unique IDs in the second column

The desired output would be:

```
structure(list(Deelnemernr. = c("4781061T0", "4781074T0", "4781076T0", 
"4781087T0", "4781047T0", "4781027T0", "4781024T0", "4781022T0", 
"4781017T0", "4781023T0", "4781078T0", "4781079T0", "4781063T0", 
"4781008T0", "4781026T0", "4781014T0", "4781015T0", "4781072T0", 
"4781046T0", "4781032T0", "4781077T0", "4781031T0", "4781030T0", 
"4781052T0", "4781056T0", "4781004T0", "4781043T0", "4781090T0", 
"4781036T0", "4781028T0", "4781053T0", "4781068T0", "4781048T0", 
"4781041T0", "4781050T0", "4781542T0", "4781095T0", "4781020T0", 
"4781097T0", "4781182T0"), Real_sample = c("", "4781074T0", "4781076T0", 
"4781087T0", "4781047T0", "4781027T0", "4781024T0", "4781022T0", 
"4781017T0", "4781023T0", "4781078T0", "4781079T0", "4781063T0", 
"4781008T0", "4781026T0", "4781014T0", "", "4781072T0", "4781061T0", 
"4781032T0", "4781077T0", "4781031T0", "4781030T0", "", "4781056T0", 
"4781004T0", "4781043T0", "4781090T0", "4781036T0", "4781028T0", 
"4781053T0", "4781068T0", "4781048T0", "4781041T0", "4781050T0", 
"4781542T0", "4781095T0", "4781020T0", "4781097T0", "4781182T0"
), days = c(16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may arrange the data by `days` and select the first row.

This can be done using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(days) %>%
  distinct(Real_sample, .keep_all = TRUE)

# A tibble: 38 × 3
#   Deelnemernr. Real_sample  days
#   <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 4781046T0    4781061T0      14
# 2 4781074T0    4781074T0      NA
# 3 4781076T0    4781076T0      NA
# 4 4781087T0    4781087T0      NA
# 5 4781047T0    4781047T0      NA
# 6 4781027T0    4781027T0      NA
# 7 4781024T0    4781024T0      NA
# 8 4781022T0    4781022T0      NA
# 9 4781017T0    4781017T0      NA
#10 4781023T0    4781023T0      NA
# ℹ 28 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Or in base R -

```
df1 <- df[order(df$days), ]
df1[!duplicated(df1$Real_sample), ]
```